# Passsing JSON in OnClick Events

Tags: javascript

How can I embed the following parameter string in an onclick event without breaking the JS? Right now there is collision with double Quotes. the values in th onclick event are coming from a JS variable.

Ex:

```
initializeMap('["2012-02-17 15:39:19.0,33.38727791932264,-86.74324840021933","2012-01-10 00:40:08.0,33.38708092092858,-86.74331461676397"]','%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f');
```

In an Onclick Event:

```
<a href="#-" onclick="JavaScript:initializeMap('["2012-02-17 15:39:19.0,33.38727791932264,-86.74324840021933","2012-01-10 00:40:08.0,33.38708092092858,-86.74331461676397"]','%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f');">Click Me</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: (a) The label `JavaScript:` is unnecessary there. You could use `Foo:` as well. (b) That's an example for a situation where using something else than inline event handlers is more appropriate. Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html. Otherwise you have to encode the double quotes, which is annoying imo.

Comment: Are you really sure you need to add the handlers inline like that?

Answer (score 2):

Like Jake said, this is better to handle without inline handlers. Nobody nowadays should be using inline handlers. Having said that, there are two options:

- You can HTML escape your JS string, it would look like : `"[&quot;2012-02-17 15:39:19.0,33.38727791932264,-86.74324840021933&quot;,&quot;2012-01-10 00:40:08.0,33.38708092092858,-86.74331461676397&quot;]"`
- You don't really need the quotes around the JSON, since it's valid JavaScript

Comment: Oooops, I actually used url encoding (which is what `escape` does) when I should have used HTML encoding... fixing it...

Comment: Here's how to escape HTML in JS http://shebang.brandonmintern.com/foolproof-html-escaping-in-javascript

Comment: Note that brandonmintern DOT com expired and is now parked. The new shebang address is http://shebang.mintern.net/foolproof-html-escaping-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a JS handler for the onclick event.

If you are stuck with inline JS, try using

```
<a href="#-" onclick='initializeMap(["2012-02-17 15:39:19.0,33.38727791932264,-86.74324840021933",
"2012-01-10 00:40:08.0,33.38708092092858,-86.74331461676397"],"%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f");'>Click Me</a>
```